# Issue with Next.js 13, Supabase, and Server Actions in layout.tsx

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, supabase, next.js13

I'm working on a Next.js 13 application and trying to manage user authentication with Supabase. I'm running into problems when I attempt to check if a user is logged in using an asynchronous function inside my layout component. Specifically, I'm using server actions with the `getSessionStatus` function to see if a user is logged in.

Here's the code snippet for my `RootLayout` component:

```js
import Link from 'next/link';
import './globals.css';
import { createServerComponentClient } from "@supabase/auth-helpers-nextjs";
import { Database } from "@/types/supabase";
import { cookies } from "next/headers";

export const metadata = {
  title: 'Create Next App',
  description: 'Generated by create next app',
};

export default function RootLayout({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) {
  async function getSessionStatus() {
    'use server';
    const supabase = createServerComponentClient<Database>({ cookies });
    const {
      data: { session },
    } = await supabase.auth.getSession();

    return Boolean(session);
  }

  const isLoggedIn = getSessionStatus();

  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        {/* Add any necessary head tags here */}
      </head>
      <body>
        <nav className="flex items-center justify-between flex-wrap bg-teal-500 p-6">
          <div className="flex items-center flex-shrink-0 text-white mr-6">
            {/* ... logo code ... */}
          </div>
          <div className="block lg:hidden">
            {/* ... button code ... */}
          </div>
          <div className="w-full block flex-grow lg:flex lg:items-center lg:w-auto">
            <div className="text-sm lg:flex-grow">
              <Link href="/ingresos" passHref>
                <span className="block mt-4 lg:inline-block lg:mt-0 text-teal-200 hover:text-white">
                  Ingresos
                </span>
              </Link>
            </div>
            <div>
              {isLoggedIn ? (
                <button className="inline-block text-sm px-4 py-2 leading-none border rounded text-white border-white hover:border-transparent hover:text-teal-500 hover:bg-white lg:mt-0">Log Out</button>
              ) : (
                <>
                  <button className="inline-block text-sm px-4 py-2 leading-none border rounded text-white border-white hover:border-transparent hover:text-teal-500 hover:bg-white lg:mt-0 mr-2">Log In</button>
                  <button className="inline-block text-sm px-4 py-2 leading-none border rounded text-white border-white hover:border-transparent hover:text-teal-500 hover:bg-white lg:mt-0">Sign Up</button>
                </>
              )}
            </div>
          </div>
        </nav>
        <main className="min-h-screen bg-background flex flex-col items-center">
          {children}
        </main>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

In this code, I'm using the `getSessionStatus` function, defined as a server action, to see if a user is logged in and then displaying different buttons based on that status.

I'm facing this issue:

1. **TypeScript Error**: I receive a TypeScript error stating `This condition will always return true since this 'Promise<boolean>' is always defined.ts(2801)`. How should I correctly handle this Promise?

I've been reading the documentation but still can't figure out how to implement this correctly in my layout component with the use of server actions. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please mention the lines you are getting the above 2 issues

Comment: Hi!

Regarding the issues we were discussing, I have some updates:

1. **The second issue (`isLoggedIn is not defined`) has disappeared on its own.** I'm not quite sure why, but I'll keep an eye on it.

2. **TypeScript Error**: I'm still facing the error stating `"This condition will always return true since this 'Promise<boolean>' is always defined.ts(2801)`. I noticed that the warning also includes a message `"layout.tsx(47, 16): Did you forget to use 'await'?`", and it's pointing to the line with `{isLoggedIn ? (`.

Comment: Thats because `isLoggedIn` is a `Promise`. You have to add `await` like: `const isLoggedIn = await getSessionStatus();`

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion to use `await` with the `getSessionStatus` function. I tried implementing it as you recommended with:

```typescript
const isLoggedIn = await getSessionStatus();
```

Unfortunately, I'm now encountering a new TypeScript error: `'await' expressions are only allowed within async functions and at the top levels of modules.ts(1308)`.

It seems that I'm not able to use `await` outside an asynchronous function in this context.

Comment: Change your `RootLayout` function to `export default async function RootLayout`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with your code is that `getSessionStatus()` is returning a `Promise`, which is always `true`.

Which is the TypeScript error:

```
This condition will always return true since this 'Promise<boolean>' is always defined.ts(2801)
```

To fix that, we shall use `await` for response of `getSessionStatus()`.

To handle `await` in your layout, we need to make the `RootLayout` function as `async`.

Here is the fixed code:

```
export default async function RootLayout({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) {
  async function getSessionStatus() {
    'use server';
    const supabase = createServerComponentClient<Database>({ cookies });
    const {
      data: { session },
    } = await supabase.auth.getSession();

    return Boolean(session);
  }

  const isLoggedIn = await getSessionStatus();

  // return html code
}
```